# Задача найти сумму ряда в интервале с заданной точностью на c++

Tags: c++

Нужно найти сумму ряда S = ln^n(5)*x^n/n! в интервале (0,1; 1) с заданной точностью eps = 1e-5.

Я нашел рекуррентную формулу и написал данный код

```
    #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double Sum(double n)
{
    double Rn, eps, sum;
    eps = 1e-5;
    Rn = 1;
    sum = Rn;
    while(abs(Rn)>eps)
    {
        Rn *= log(5)/(n+1);
        sum += Rn;
    }
    return sum;
}
void print(double xmin = 0.1, double xmax = 1, int N)
{
    int h;
    h = (xmax - xmin)/N;
    double x, y;
    for (int i; i<N; i++)
    {
        x = xmin + i*h;
        y = Sum(x);
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Выдает ошибку.
Можете посмотреть, что не так или же подсказать как правильно выполнить данное задание.
P.S Я не очень разбираюсь в программировании, так что можно пожалуйста по подробнее.

Comment: "Выдает ошибку." - Никогда... Слышите? Никогда! ... не говорите, какая у Вас возникает ошибка. Здесь собрались профессионалы, которые обожают угадывать.

Comment: А где функция main()?

Comment: @Ivan Какая разница где main? Этот код не скомпилируется.

Comment: Какое-то бредовое задание. Вам дали ряд, сумма которого всегда равна `5**x` ("пять в степени икс" не зависимо от точности. если `n` идёт от нуля), при этом вы зачем-то суммируете эти `5**x` по некоторым `x` из заданного интервала. Вообще непонятно.

Comment: @Zealint, нормальное учебное задание.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ознакомьтесь что такое **Рекурентная формула**, потому что в
   представленной вами функции вы пытаетесь последовательно определить
   каждый член, и нет у вас никакой рекурентной формулы.
2. Не нужно хорошо разбираться в программировании, чтобы решить данную
   задачу. В своем коде вы показали, что умеете объявлять переменные,
   придать им значения, использовать их, написать функцию и написать
   цикл.  Так что вы сможете выполнить следующее:

---

- Найти первый член ряда
- Если есть `к` _ тый член ряда, определить функцию(действие) **F**(k) для получения
  `к + 1` _ того члена ряда.
- Определить константу `a` чтобы действие **F**(a) выдало первый
  член, и sum = 0;

Чтобы найти член, имеющий заданную точность `eps`, нужно понять: имеет ли каждый член значение меньше единицы по абсолютному значению? Если да, то выполняем следующее(в вашем случаи все члены положительны, поэтому нет нужды получать их абсолютное значение):

```
while(sum > eps) {
 a = F(a);
 sum += a;
}
```

И выдать  `sum` как ответ, и никакая функция `print` тут не нужна, где вы непонятно что делаете или непонятно откуда скопировали. Решать нужно пытаться самостоятельно, но а если вам программирование не интересует вовсе(и в этом нет ничего плохого, если вас интересует другая профессия), то  решите вашу проблему по другому_ не там, где помогают разобраться в конкретных вопросах, а не выполняют за кого_то...